# Distant HasManyThrough

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I have four Models:

1. User
2. Client
3. Store
4. Opportunity

The relationships are defined as such:

- User hasMany Client
- Client hasMany Store
- Store hasMany Opportunity
- User hasManyThrough Store, Client (this works)

The problem is that I'm attempting to access the User->Opportunity relationship via built-in Laravel relationships, but it doesn't seem as if I can do it without a custom Query or an additional user_id column on the opportunities table to allow direct access (even though one can be inferred from the Store->Client relationship). I'm also not a fan of nested `foreach` loops if they can be avoided.

My question:

Is there a way to go one level deeper and directly access a User's Opportunities in this scenario? The actual Model code and all relevant relationships are as follows:

*User*

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    public function clients(){
        return $this->hasMany('Client');
    }
    public function stores(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Store', 'Client');
    }
    public function proposals(){
        return $this->hasMany('Proposal');
    }
    public function opportunities(){ //This does the job, but I feel like it could be better
        return Opportunity::join('stores', 'stores.id', '=', 'opportunities.store_id')->
                            join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'stores.client_id')->
                            join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.user_id')->
                            select('opportunities.*')->
                            where('users.id', $this->id);
    }
    public function getOpportunitiesAttribute(){ //This just helps mimic the hasManyThrough shorthand
        return $this->opportunities()->get();       
    }
}
```

*Client*

```
class Client extends Eloquent{
    public function stores(){
        return $this->hasMany('Store');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function opportunities(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Opportunity', 'Store');
    }
}
```

*Store*

```
class Store extends Eloquent {
    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Client');
    }
    public function opportunities(){
        return $this->hasMany('Opportunity');
    }
}
```

*Opportunity*

```
class Opportunity extends Eloquent {
    public function store(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Store');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Laravell but from my Java Persistance API experience, I can say that you need a custom query for such a problem or, as you mentioned it, a relationship between user and oportunity directly.

Comment: @ITroubs Yeah, that's what it's looking like so far. Still, if I can have my cake and eat it too, that would be awesome.

Comment: Your solution with `joins` is pertty much the best you can do. Otherwise you can create custom relation for this very case, that will work like `hasManyThorugh` but with 1 more nesting level.

Comment: Using the joins like you have is how I do distant relationships too. Haven't found another way yet, but it ought to be possible by creating a relationship in a similar way to how `hasManyThrough()` does it. This package does `belongsToThrough()` and manages multiple levels, so could serve as inspiration: https://github.com/znck/belongs-to-through

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such method in Laravel. You have to create your custom query. This custom query can be very expensive since multiple queries will be performed. Thus, the optimum solution for this, according to me, is to relate User and Opportunity with a foreign key.

However, if you don't desire to link User and Opportunity with a foreign key, then you can create a custom query to handle this. Simply add a "hasManyThrough" relation between Opportunity and Client model like,

```
    <?php
    class Client extends Eloquent{
        public function store(){
            return $this->hasMany('Store');
        }
        public function user(){
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }

        public function opportunity(){
            return $this->hasManyThrough('Opportunity', 'Store');
        }
    }
```

Then create a static function in User model.

```
    <?php

    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

        use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

        public function client(){
            return $this->hasMany('Client');
        }
        public function store(){
            return $this->hasManyThrough('Store', 'Client');
        }

        public static function getOpportunityOfUser($userId)
        {
             $clients = User::find($userId)->client;

            foreach ($clients as $client) {
                $opportunities[] = Client::find($client->id)->opportunity;
            }

            return $opportunities;
        }
    }
```

Now you can access Opportunity realted to a User in one go like,

```
    Route::get('/', function()
    {   
         return $usersOpportunities = User::getOpportunityOfUser(1);
    });
```

This will return all opportunity of all clients related to User with id '1'.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. It's not a *bad* way of handling it, but separating out model queries like that will result in multiple queries to the database which can get expensive.

Comment: Also, this won't really work. Users have many clients. Clients have many Opportunities through Stores (as shown in my original example). This only retrieves the first client, not all of them. I'm looking to return all Opportunities for a given user regardless of client or store. I think you're right, in that a custom query is the only way to go on this.

Comment: IF you want opportunity of all clients then you can loop through $client array and fetch opportunity associated with that client. Again, that fetched opportunity's data needs to be pushed in a array which will be returned once loop is finished. In this way you will get an array of opportunity associated with many clients that have same user id. Yes, it is quite expensive. You have to do a lot of things and multiple query will be run. So, the optimum solution is to link User and Opportunity with a foreign key. In that way you can get your desired data in one query.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Now, it retrieves all of the clients and their opportunities related to a same user id.

Comment: This **is a bad way** of handling it. Count queries that you run with this code, then you will know why. Also creating artificial relation (fk user-opportunities) is not the best solution. OP `joins` are much more efiicient and better way of chieving this. Misleading relation names are another thing against this answer. That's why -1.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I know it runs multiple query which slows down the application. That's why I said the optimal solution is to link User and Opportunity with a foreign key. I pictured this way to prove that it is possible to achieve what he desires by building custom query. Just it's possible does not mean you have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function opportunities() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Opportunity::class, [Client::class, Store::class]);
    }
}
```