# Applying hasManyThrough to deeper relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

The Laravel docs seem to indicate that the `hasManyThrough` declaration can only be used for relationships that are two levels "deep". What about more complex relationships? For example, a `User` has many `Subject`s, each of which has many `Deck`s, each of which has many `Card`s. It's simple to get all `Deck`s belonging to a `User` using the `hasManyThrough` declaration, but what about all `Card`s belonging to a `User`?

Comment: [I asked this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938081/distant-hasmanythrough) a few years ago. HasManyThrough is simply a shortcut. As it stands, there is no built in mechanism for accessing distant relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `hasManyThrough` doesn't support this level of specificity. One of the things you can do is return a query builder instance going the opposite direction:

```
//App\User;

public function cards()
{
    Card::whereHas('decks', function($q){
         return $q->whereHas('subjects', function($q){
            return $q->where('user_id', $this->id);
        });
    });
}
```

We're going from `Cards -> Decks -> Subjects`. The `subjects` should have a `user_id` column that we can then latch onto.

When called from the user model, it would be done thussly:

```
$user->cards()->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function cards() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Card::class, [Subject::class, Deck::class]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually the best solution will be put the extra column to Card table - user_id, if you have so frequent needs to get all cards for the user.

Laravel provides Has-Many-Through relations for 2-depth relation because this is very widely often used relation.
For the relations Laravel does not support, you need to figure out the best table relationship yourself.

Any way, for your purpose, you can use following code snap to grab all cards for the user, with your current relation model.

> Assumption

- User has `hasManyThough` relationship to Deck,

So Project model will have following code:

```
 public function decks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Deck', 'Subject');
    }
```

- Deck has `hasMany` relationship to Card

> Code

```
$deck_with_cards = $user->decks()->with("cards")->get();
$cards = [];
foreach($deck_with_cards AS $deck) {
  foreach ($deck->cards as $c) {
    $cards[] = $c->toArray();
  }
}
```

Now `$cards` has all cards for the `$user`.